# When i download something and click 'show in folder' nothing happens

Tags: files, downloads, location

I am running the newest Ubuntu, when I download something, such as an mp3 file, and click on <kbd>Show in Folder</kbd>, absolutely nothing happens.

Is there an easy fix for this, without being technical and using scripts? All I want to do is see where the file is located after it has downloaded.

(I have looked all over for a solution with no luck).

Comment: Which browser do you use to download these files?

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution without using show in folder. In the top left corner of your Ubuntu sidebar, click Search. Then type in  "Files" and open it. Navigate to Downloads and there the file will be. The same way Windows files or Mac would be stored in their respective file managers, Ubuntu's will too. I would recommend (If you do not already) having Files on your sidebar for quick access to all files.